# Неявная переадресация поддомена

Tags: .htaccess, редирект, поддомены

Добрый день. Уже много раз поднимался подобный вопрос, но везде либо один и  тот же ответ и он не работает. Маны скурены, гугл уже поломан.
Есть домен site.ru Включена обработка поддоменов. Необходимо по запросу news.site.com неявно переадресовывать на site.com/news. Т.е. в адресной строке должно остаться news.site.com. Проект написан на кохане, соответсвенно папки news нет в каталоге с сайтом.
Явная переадресация работает. Однако мне нужно оставить адрес news.site.com без 301 кода

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum\.domain\.(com|ru)$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/forum/
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /forum/$1 [L]
```

Насколько я понял по манам rewriterule работает только со строкой запроса с отсеченным адресом до файла .htacess. Соответственно, неявно изменить http_host, т.е. домен/поддомен его средствами невозможно?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L,QSA] # скрываю index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^news\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /news/$1 [L]
```

В таком случае вообще не работает - происходит зацикливание 
news/index.php?news/index.php&news/index.php

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^news\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_FINISH} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /news/$1 [L,E=FINISH:1]
```

В таком варианте зацикливания нет, но все равно открывается главная страница news.site.com - аналогичная главной site.com, т.к. включена обработка поддоменов.

Подскажите пожалуйста - то что я хочу от htacess вообще реально или нет?
Можно, в принципе, выдать страницу news.site.com/news. Но в этом случае не тянуться шрифты с другого домена. Нужно выключать кеширование статических файлов для включения Access-Control-Allow-Origin, что тоже не очень хочется делать. Можно сделать копипаст кода в поддомен news - но тоже не интересно следить потом за двумя одинаковыми проектами. Тем более, что скорее всего понадобится еще один поддомен аналогичный news. Вообщем, помогите пожалуйста.
Нужна вся эта затея для получения ссылочной массы с поддоменов со статьями на основной домен.